# How to append return value of function into list in Pool?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, pool

I'm curious if it is possible to append a return value from function f(x,y) into, for example, list.

So I have this:

**Parallel:**

```
 def download_unit_LVs(self, cislo_uzemia):
     pool = Pool(number_of_workers)
     for cislo in cisla:
         pool.apply_async(self.download_cislo, args=(cislo_uzemia,cislo))
     pool.close()
     pool.join()
     self.manager.commit()
```

This is the way how I run the method `self.download_cislo` parallel but the problem is, that it returns a value which I have to append to results list.

How to do that?

**Sequential**:

```
 def download_unit_LVs(self, cislo_uzemia):
        results = []
        for cislo in cisla:
            results.append(self.download_cislo(cislo_uzemia,cislo))
        self.manager.commit()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `pool.apply_async` call can be passed a [`callback`
function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async). The
callback function will be called when `foo` function completes and will be
passed the value returned by `foo`. Note that the return value [must be picklable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), as the communication between processes is done with a Queue.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(x):
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = []
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for i in range(100):
        pool.apply_async(foo, args=(i, ), callback=result.append)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(result)
    # [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, ... 9409, 9604, 9801]
```

Comment: The `lambda` expression is unnecessary, just pass `result.append` as `callback`. In this example callbacks and the loop are also unnecessary because those can be replaced by `Pool.map()` which already returns a list with all results.

Comment: I just tested both options with `map` and `apply_async` and `apply_async` is faster, thanks!

Comment: In your example, the list follows the correct order of the `for` loop. But when I apply it to my real case, half of the elements in the list are in the wrong order. How to make sure they append in the correct order?

Answer (score 1):

If the results should end up in a list use the `map()` method of the `Pool`:

```
def download_unit_LVs(self, cislo_uzemia):
    pool = Pool(number_of_workers)
    results = pool.map(partial(self.download_cislo, cislo_uzemia), self.cisla)
    self.manager.commit()
```

`partial()` is from the `functools` module.